# MySql server “Error No. 2003 Can't connect to Mysql server”, I can't connect, I've already changed my.cnf and created remote users

Tags: mysql, server, gcloud

My server is running in google cloud platform, I'm going to show the specifications here:

mysql version : Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

The MySql configuration file is located in `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf`

I already have changed the line from `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` to `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`, after that I restarted the service with `sudo mysql service restart`

Then I created users and allow remote connections, here is a list of my users:

[image]

I have been trying to connect through sqlyog client, but it keeps throwing the same error message:

[image]

Comment: try to connect from your local machine using the mysql command line client. If that works, you might have a firewall in your way. Port 3306 has to be opened.

Comment: i tried to connect from my computer using the console, it keeps throwing the same error, do you know any way to check if there is a firewall blocking the port? actually, i'm not an expert about servers configurations, but i do my best to learn, thanks for your support

Comment: @jorgealbertoherrerarodrguez, In Google Cloud Platform, you can open a port by creating a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls). This [example](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access) explains how to create two instances on Google Compute Engine, the MySQL server and the client which connects internally (to server) using firewall rules. In your case, and since you are connecting from outside GCE, you need to create the firewall rule from “Source IP range”= 0.0.0.0/0  with “specified protocols and ports” = tcp:3306

Comment: Hello fady, thank you so much, your answer helped me a lot, now it works, I did exactly what you say, but there was only one detail, an important one, in the firewall rules, the rule called default-allow-internal, it has a default tcp value with tcp:1-65545, just changed that to 1-3305, then add the new firewall rule to allow remote mysql access, and now it's working, again thank you so much fady !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue, This is for debian 9, and mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, I'm going to write the steps here:

1- First I edited this file /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf,
just find the line bind-address            = 127.0.0.1 if it's commented just uncomment it, change the address to 0.0.0.0 to allow traffic from everywhere,
after that use service mysql restart command to restart mysql service

2.- In gcloud click on your instance > go to the network interface section and click > click on firewall rules section > select the "default-allow-internal" firewall rule, and change tcp:1-65545 to tcp:1-3305, and save it.

3.- Add a new firewall rule > source filter > select Ip intervals > set 0.0.0.0/0, protocols and ports set tcp:3306, save it and that's it

4.- Add remote mysql users, examples:

```
CREATE USER 'myus'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypas'; # To connect from the 
server
CREATE USER 'myus'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypas'; # To connect from everywhere
```

## To give permissions to the users

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myus'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypas' WITH 
GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myus'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypas' WITH GRANT 
OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

this worked for me, i hope it works for you too

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution. I find it strange that the internal firewall rule port range solved the issue. I think it may have only been a delay until the firewall updated the rule that allowed external traffic through tcp:3306 (point #3).However, I am glad it works now.

Comment: Yes, so I did, I thought that default-allow-internal it was only to allow traffic between compute engine instances, but I found an official solution of gcloud, that was what completed the answers that I needed, here is where I found the instruction to change default-allow-internal, in the **Advanced networking considerations** section 

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access